# Is `synchronized` the only way to ensure thread-safety when modifying collection inside ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

I have a `static final ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Queue<User>> MAP`, which contains `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` for values, and I need to frequently modify queues inside the map while ensuring that no other thread can intervene. I've tried to gather pieces of information and best practice on how to handle thread-safety of nested collections, and it seems that the only way is to `synchronized` all modifications to the nested collection.

My add method

```
public static void add(Long id, User user) {
    Queue<User> q = MAP.get(id);
    if (q != null) {
        synchronized(q) {
            if (q != null) {
                q.offer(user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My remove method

```
public static void remove(Long id, User user) {
    Queue<User> q = MAP.get(id);
    if (q != null) {
        synchronized (q) {
            if(q != null) {
                q.remove(user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it correct or maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: If the `MAP` should only hold `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`s as values, I would advice to redefine its type as `ConcurrentHashMap<Long, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<User>>`. --- I do not fully understand why `synchronized` should be needed in the given example. After all, a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is thread-safe.

Comment: @Turing85 As I read there is a possibility of race condition when multiple operations involved, e.g. between check for null and offer/remove

Comment: By "*check for null*", you mean `q != null`? If so: no, this will not interfer with  `offer`/`remove`. A possible use case for `synchronized` would be if we need to remove one value and add another value to the queue while ensuring that no other thread is doing the same or if we needed to do operations on two data structures in a synchronized way (i.e. at one point in time, at most one thread can perform this operation-"*block*")

Comment: It is still confusing. What if one thread checks for `q != null` and is about to add / remove a new element to that queue, but then another thread intervenes, does the same and completes the operation before first thread? Shouldn't we take care of that scenario?

Comment: `q` is either null or not. After `Queue<User> q = MAP.get(id);` has been executed, no other thread can change the outcome of the `null`-check. As per your definition, `MAP` only holds `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`s as values. `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` takes care of thread-safety, so we are free to call methods like `offer(...)` and `remove(...)` without further snychronization. The synchronization happens within the method calls.

Comment: @Turing85 you're absolutely right. Thank you!

Comment: In fact, given `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` itself doesn't use `synchronized` for its internal operations, using it in your code will not necessarily make it thread-safe if the queue is also accessible and used elsewhere.

Comment: No real answer can be given as long as the code example is an incomplete sketch. Silently doing nothing if the key is absent, surely isn’t the real life strategy of your application, is it? Further, assuming the the application is supposed to do *something*, at least some keys must map to an actual queue. You haven’t shown when and how those queues are put into the map. E.g., when your application only initializes the map once and never puts nor removes entries afterwards, you don’t even need a `ConcurrentHashMap`. But if mappings can change, `synchronized` can not prevent race conditions here

Answer (score 1):

Access to the nested collection needs to be thread-safe, but the use of *synchronized* is just one means of providing thread-safety (and often not the preferred means):

- For collections that are already thread-safe and specifically designed for efficient concurrent access, including ConcurrentLinkedQueue, you don't generally need additional synchronisation-- you should use these where possible;
- If the collection is not thread-safe and there is no available equivalent that is naturally thread-safe, then *synchronized* can be a simple solution, but it comes with the caveats that it will exclusively lock the collection during all reads and writes (so even while the collection is not being modified and theoretically, multiple threads could read at the same time, only one read at a time is possible), and in most implementations is "last in, first out", meaning that under high concurrency, accessors at the back of the queue can get starved access for longer periods of time-- still, it can be appropriate when the actual reads/writes are very fast;
- Using one of Java's explicit locks (e.g. ReentrantLock, ReentrantReadWriteLock) can be more appropriate when the actual collection read/write operations are more complex and/or you need to guarantee fairness and/or reads outnumber writes and you want to allow concurrent reads while the collection is not being modified.

All of the above presupposes that:

- Having one collection nested within another is indeed the appropriate data structure for your purpose;
- Your access to the outer ConcurrentHashMap is correct (e.g. in your example, you must have pre-populated the map; if you are adding new queues on the fly, you need to deal properly with the potential race condition of two threads concurrently trying to create a queue for the same ID for the first time).